# iAd banner shown on simulator but not shown when app live

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I have make an outlet of ADBannerView from Xib, then add required delegate methods, After complete the coding procedure when i app run on simulator, ADBanner shows the default view in AddBannerView that is correct but when the same app live on App store it do not shows any add. Why?

Comment: It will take additional time till the iAd Review has been passed. On my App, it took 5 days after the App was in the store till the first requests came thru.

Comment: Thanks @jboi, but on my side 20 days have passed of app live

Answer (score 0):

***It always takes some days until they show up.***

First of all the app is **reviewed** and approved for the **app** **store** and later on it will be reviewed from the **iAd** **Network** **team**. If it takes a long time and you don't get any response you should try contacting the support. But don't you worry too early, they always take some time.

Answer (score 0):

20 days is too long. Please check on iTunesConnect if you see any requests coming thru. https://iad.apple.com/itcportal/#app_homepage `Requests` are the one thing your app should always send out, no matter from which country it was called. 
If not, and the Banner did work during simulation, contact Apple support.

If the above link does not work, go to [iTunesConnect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com), login with your AppleId and navigate to `iAd`.